# Problem with program's output redirection

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am supposed to put the following command in the system function argument in a C program.

```
$ timed-run 20 prog1 1 1>/dev/null 2>abc.dat
```

`timed-run` is supposed to execute `prog1` up to 20 seconds and then terminate it. I want the output of `prog1` to be redirected to `abc.dat`. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr: `timed-run 20 prog1 2>/dev/null 1>abc.dat` . I didn't get your question - what isn't working? Do you need to write the program 'timed-run'?

Comment: Well, the timed-run script is already provided by expect package in linux. I want to discard the output of stdout but want to have the output of stderr i.e. 2 to be redirected to abc.dat. In fact there is also an argument to prog1 i.e. $ timed-run 20 prog1 1 2>abc.dat 1>/dev/null

Comment: So what about this isn't working when you tried it?

Comment: No. its not working. abc.dat is empty after execution.

Answer (score 1):

When you write "1> /dev/null", you are redirecting the output of the program to the bit-bucket.  (That is, you are discarding it.)  If you write "1>filename" instead, the output will go to the named file.

Comment: The desired output is infact being produced through stderr instead of stdout. So, I have to use 2>abc.dat instead of 1>abc.dat

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Note that the way you've written it, abc.dat will contain whatever timed-run writes to stderr.  Possibly the timed-run program is not correctly dealing with the IO streams of prog1.

Answer (score 1):

For redirecting child process output there are several ways, Following 2 are the most importants:

1. popen() (The easy one to understand and use, but popen works only with stdout of child, but you can redirect stderr to stdout as well by appending to command line string "2>&1")
2. pipe fork and exec trio will help you (there are lot of info about this functions in internet)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, but can't know without seeing the `prog1` source code, that `prog1` is not flushing its output buffers. That is, it has code that looks like:

```
i = 42;
fprintf(stderr, "result: %d\n", i);
```

The formatted output (i.e. "result: 42\n") is being stored in `stderr`'s output buffer waiting for an opportune to be written. But, before that can happen, `timed-run` kills `prog1` with a signal.

Your choices are to either call `fflush(stderr)` periodically, change the buffering type (with `setbuf` or `setvbuf`), or catch the signal and call `fflush(stderr)` at program termination.